# How can I append to a specific dictionary within an array of dictionaries in swift?

Tags: swift

My data structure:

```
var defs = [["a":"b","c":"d"],["e":"f","g":"h"]]
```

I have tried the following:

```
dict[1]["testKey"] = "testValue"
```

in an attempt to attain the following:

```
defs = [["a":"b","c":"d"],["e":"f","g":"h","testKey":"testValue"]]
```

This doesn't work though. Does anyone have a good solution?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". We must assume you mean your code won't compile because there is no `dict` variable.

Comment: my bad, I do actually use defs instead of dict, that was just a typo. Should it work that way?

Comment: 1) Update your question with the actual code you are trying. 2) Update your question with a clear explanation of what issue you are having with the code. Keep in mind that "doesn't work" is a a useless statement. Describe in clear, exact detail the actual issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code (I see you're using `dict` instead of `defs` but this works fine:

```
var defs = [
    [
        "a": "b",
        "c": "d"
    ],
    [
        "e": "f",
        "g": "h"
    ]
]

defs[1]["key"] = "value"
print(defs[1]["key"]) // "Optional("value")\n"
```

Comment: Thank you, my issue was actually something else, but you're right that works

Answer (score 0):

```
 var defs = [["a":"b","c":"d"],["e":"f","g":"h"]]
 defs[1]["testKey"] = "testValue"
 print(defs)
```

prints:

```
[["a": "b", "c": "d"], ["e": "f", "testKey": "testValue", "g": "h"]]
```

The elements contained within the `defs` array are of type `Dictionary`, which by definition is unordered. If the order is an issue, you have to use another collection type.

Comment: Possibly you ment what I'm about to wrote (and just "typo-ed"), but note that `defs` in itself is ordered (it's an array). The elements of `defs`, however, are of type `[String: String]` dictionaries, and these are in themselves, unordered (which is probably what you ment in the first place).